# Pythons inspect.getsource throws error if used in a decorator

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following function

```
def foo():
    for _ in range(1):
        print("hello")
```

Now I want to add another print statement to print "Loop iterated" after every loop iteration. For this I define a new function that transforms foo into an ast tree, inserts the corresponding print node and then compiles the ast tree into an executable function:

```
def modify(func):

    def wrapper():
        
        source_code = inspect.getsource(func)
        ast_tree = ast.parse(source_code)

        # insert new node into ast tree
        for node in ast.walk(ast_tree):
            if isinstance(node, ast.For):
                node.body += ast.parse("print('Loop iterated')").body

        # get the compiled function
        new_func = compile(ast_tree, '<ast>', 'exec')
        namespace = {}
        exec(new_func, globals(), namespace)
        new_func = namespace[func.__name__]
        
        return new_func()

    return wrapper
```

This works fine as expected when using:

```
foo = modify(foo)
foo()
```

However, if I decide to use `modify` as a decorator:

```
@modify
def foo():
    for _ in range(1):
        print("hello")
foo()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\noinn\Documents\decorator_test\test.py", line 34, in <module>
    foo()
  File "c:\Users\noinn\Documents\decorator_test\test.py", line 25, in wrapper
    return new_func()
  File "c:\Users\noinn\Documents\decorator_test\test.py", line 11, in wrapper
    source_code = inspect.getsource(func)
  File "C:\Users\noinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 1024, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "C:\Users\noinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 1006, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "C:\Users\noinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 835, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code
```

Does anyone know why that error appears? Note that this does not happen If I return the original function and the error only appears once new_func() is called.

------------------------- Solution ----------------------

Simply remove the decorator from the function in the decorator itself using:

```
ast_tree.body[0].decorator_list = []
```

Comment: Hello there! When I run your first example it doesn't work for me either. Could you confirm that it definitely does work for you?

Comment: Also, is there are reason why you want to modify the ast directly rather than writing a more conventional wrapper?

Comment: @PirateNinjas I added two pictures with the respective code. I can confirm that the one case definitely works for me. Also yes, the reason is that I want to insert large chunks of code into functions without the need to manually add them to every function

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why that needs you to modify the AST for the function definition. Could you include a more complete example?

Comment: @PirateNinjas assume for example that I want to keep track of how many iterations of for looping have been done in my code. I could now have a global `counter` variable and manually add `counter += 1` at the end of every for loop. However, imagine more complex things, then the code quickly becomes unreadable and it gets hard to keep track of all the for loops. So it would be easier to have a decorator who adds `counter += 1` for me. Then the original source code would be more tidy and I dont have to worry about missing a foor loop.

Comment: If your loop calls a function, wouldn't it be easier to decorate the called function and add a counter there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found out my initial hypothesis is incorrect: `inspect.getsource` is smart enough to retrieve the source code even if the function name is not yet set in the module globals.  (surprisingly).

What happens is that the source code is retrieved along with the *decorator* calls as well, and when the function is called, the decorator runs again - so, it gets some re-entrancy in `inspect.getsource`, at which points it fails.

The solution bellow work: I just strip decorators at the module  level in the retrieved source code, before feeding it to `ast.parse`

I also rearranged your decorator, as it would re-read the source code, and reparse the AST at each time the decorated function would be called - the way this example is, there is no need for an inner `wrapper` function at all. If you happen to need to parametrize your decorator, and need the inner `wrapper`, all the function re-writting parts, up to the creation of `new_func`, should be outside the wrapper, so that they run only once

```
import inspect
import ast
import functools  

def modify(func):
    func.__globals__[func.__name__] = func
    source_lines = inspect.getsource(func).splitlines()
    # strip decorators from the source itself
    source_code = "\n".join(line for line in source_lines if not line.startswith('@'))


    ast_tree = ast.parse(source_code)

    # insert new node into ast tree
    for node in ast.walk(ast_tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.For):
            node.body += ast.parse("print('Loop iterated')").body

    # get the compiled function
    new_func = compile(ast_tree, '<ast>', 'exec')
    namespace = {}
    exec(new_func, func.__globals__, namespace)
    new_func = namespace[func.__name__]

    return functools.wraps(func)(new_func)


@modify
def foo():
    for _ in range(1):
        print("hello")

#foo = modify(foo)

foo()
```

**initial answer**

Left here for the reasoning and simpler workaround:

it can't get the source of `<module>.foo` function due to the simple fact that the name `foo` will only be defined and bound after the function definition, including all its decorators, is executed.

The name `foo` simply does not exist as a variable in the module at the point the decorator code is run, although it is set as the `__name__` attribute in `func` at this point. There is nothing `inspect.getsource` can do about it.

In other words, decorator syntax is altogether off-limits if one is using `inspect.getsource` because there is nothing yet `getsource` can get the source of.

The good news is the workaround is simple: one have to give-up the `@` decorator syntax, and apply the decorator "in the old way" (as it was before Python 2.3): one declares the function as usual, and reassign its name to the return of manually calling the decorator - this is the same as is written in your working example:

```
def foo(...):
    ...


foo = modify(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out the solution was to remove the decorator from the ast tree and compile the function without the decorator :)

Comment: yes - I found that out when debugging the code trying to get a workaround. Answer updated to reflect that.

Comment: But still, what confuses me is the Traceback of the error. Because `source_code = inspect.getsource(func)` is the initial call used to get the source code and retrieve the ast tree. Before I call the compiled function, I can even print `source_code`. It makes no sense to me why Traceback would flag this line.

Comment: I found out while debugging it: as the decorator was call was passed down to the AST, the outer decorator itself was called _again_ when the function was called, resulting in a recursive call. At the time of the second call, the source code could not be find, as the `__code__` object is no longer generated from source, but synthesized at runtime.

Comment: That makes so much sense, thank you. It was totally not on my radar that the decorator is applied again.